# Saving HTML Content in database in DraftJS and retrieving the HTML Content

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, draftjs

I am using Draft.js as an editor on my website. I can show the editor text as HTML  format in the website. But I want to save this HTML data content in my database and retrieve the list content of the HTML. Here is what I have done. This is for showing the HTML content.I have used  'draftjs-to-html' for showing HTML content.

```
import draftToHtml from 'draftjs-to-html'
<Editor
    blockStyleFn={getBlockStyle}
    customStyleMap={styleMap}
    editorState={this.state.editorState}
    handleKeyCommand={this.handleKeyCommand}
    onChange={this.onChange}
    placeholder="Describe the requirements and skills needed for the job"
    ref="editor"
    spellCheck={true}
/>
<h4>Editor content as HTML</h4>
<pre>{this.state.editorContentHtml}</pre>
```

I used this function for showing the HTML content.

```
this.onChange = editorState => {
        this.setState({
            editorState,
            editorContentHtml: stateToHTML(editorState.getCurrentContent())

        });

    };
```

This is the snapshot of my editor

[image]

I want to save the html result in the database and also show it as html. Any help regarding this would be appreciated or if there is any other alternative way for retrieving data as String format.